# opengl: rotating an ellipse

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I am having trouble rotating an ellipse in OpenGL. So, I have some code to draw an ellipse as follows:

```
glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glLineWidth(2.0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, 0, 0); // ellipse centre   
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
float inc = (float) M_PI / 500.0;
for (GLfloat i = 0; i < M_PI * 2; i+=inc)
{
    float x = cos(i) * 0.4;
    float y = sin(i) * 0.4;
    glVertex2f(x, y);
}
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glPopAttrib();
```

This produces a picture as so:[image]

Now what I want to do is rotate this ellipse clockwise. So I added a glrotate in between but the result was not what I had expected.

So, I did something like:

```
glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glLineWidth(2.0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);    
glRotatef(-90, 1, 1, 0);
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
float inc = (float) M_PI / 500.0;
for (GLfloat i = 0; i < M_PI * 2; i+=inc)
{
    float x = cos(i) * 0.4;
    float y = sin(i) * 0.4;
    glVertex2f(x, y);
}

glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glPopAttrib();
```

This produced an image which was simply collapsed. What I wanted to do was rotate the ellipse along its center by the specified degrees. Also, I tried playing around with the various parameters of glRotatef but could not get it do as I expected. The resulting image looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're working in the XY plane, so you can't really rotate around a vector in XY. Instead, you want to rotate along the unit Z axis (`glRotate (angle, 0, 0, 1);`). Imagine your screen being the XY coordinate system and the Z axis pointing inwards. What you want is to rotate around the Z axis, so your XY plane remains in the XY plane.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out just as I posted but I have other issues as well! I will post a new question to highlight that...!